# Word problem on collecting specified liters with two pails

Tags: combinatorics

I am thinking through an interesting puzzle. John is near a lake and has two pails, one holding 4 liters, the other holding 7 liters. The pails have no markings. All John knows is if a pail is empty or full and the capacities of the full pails.

I am trying to determine all of the (integer) number of liters (between 1-11) that John can exactly obtain in this scenario. For instance, I know he can obtain 3 liters by filling the 7 liters pail full and transferring as much as he can into the 4 liter pail so that the remainder in the 7 liters pail is 3 liters. I am looking for a method to systematically work through determining the possibilities that can be obtained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2*4 - 7 = 1: Fill (4), pour (4) -> (7), Fill (4), pour (4) into (7) till (7) is full. 1 liter is left in 4.

2*(2*4 - 7) = 2: After doing the above, empty (7), pour the 1 liter left in (4) into (7), then do the same steps as before again. But this time you are left with 2 liters in the (4) when the (7) is filled.

3 liters can be obtained as you've indicated. Higher amounts can be obtained by putting 0, 1, 2, 3 or 4 liters in one of the buckets, then completely filling the other.

Comment: Some explanation here: first I find the g.c.d of the two bucket sizes: gcd(4,7) = 1, so any multiple of 1 liter should be possible. The gcd of x and y is the lowest positive value of ax + by for any a and b, so there is some way of expressing a*4 + b* 7 = 1, which was easy to find. After that it is just translating the math into physical steps.

Answer (score 1):

These are known as Decanting problems.

Two coded implementations are at [Water-Pouring Problem](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/WaterPouringProblem/) and [Solving Decanting Problems by Graph Theory](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/SolvingDecantingProblemsByGraphTheory/).

Martin Garnder's 6th Book has a column on the problem.